# Show matrix is positive definite, negative definite etc.. constrained to a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am trying to show the definiteness of a matrix constrained to a subspace:

$$Q=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1&1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

constrained to the subspace:

$$U=\bigg\{\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\\z \end{bmatrix}\bigg|x+y+z=0\bigg\}$$

I considered the following:

Def $u=\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\\z \end{bmatrix}$, then 
$$u^{'}Qu=2xy+2xz+2yz$$

Consider

$$2xy+2xz+2yz \hspace{4mm}\text{s.t.}  \hspace{4mm}x+y+z=0$$

Then  Since

$$2xy+2xz+2yz=2xy+2xz+2yz+2z^2-2z^2=2z(x+y+z)+2xy-2z^2$$ 
by the constraint this reduces to the equivalent problem:

$$2xy-2z^2 \hspace{4mm}\text{s.t.}  \hspace{4mm}x+y+z=0$$

Consider the case of positive semidefiniteness

$$2xy-2z^2 \ge 0 \hspace{4mm}\text{s.t.}  \hspace{4mm}x+y+z=0$$

By the constraint $z^2=x^2+y^2+2xy$

then:

$$xy\ge x^2+y^2+2xy, \forall u\in U$$

equivalently : 
$$-xy\ge x^2+y^2, \forall u\in U$$

Let $u=\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 4\\-2\end{bmatrix}$
note:

$$8 \ngeq 20$$

So cannot be positive definite. Is my logic correct before I try to show that it is negative definite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution so far is correct, but I think that there are easier ways to proceed. The observation in [Malkoun’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3608437/265466) leads to the simplest solution, but if you don’t notice that $Q$ can be rewritten in that convenient form, there’s another way that I think is simpler than yours.

Choose a convenient basis for $U$, say, $(1,-1,0)^T$ and $(1,0,-1)^T$. Relative to this basis, the restriction of $Q$ to $U$ has the matrix $$Q' = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\\1&0&-1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-2&-1\\-1&-2\end{bmatrix}.$$ Test this matrix for definiteness.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $Q(x,y,z) = 2(xy+xz+yz)$, then:

$$Q(x,y,z) = -(x^2+y^2+z^2) + (x+y+z)^2.$$

Use that to deduce that $Q$ is negative definite on $\{x+y+z = 0\}$.

Comment: Is my work for non positive definiteness correct

Comment: Yes, your logic above is correct. I just checked all the details. It is more complicated though than what I propose, but it is correct.